# Retrieve last row of a data frame with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) as

```
                                   Open          High           Low         Close      Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits
Datetime                                                                                                          
2022-03-08 09:55:00+05:30  15829.900391  15832.049805  15819.950195  15831.750000           0          0             0
2022-03-08 09:56:00+05:30  15830.750000  15839.349609  15818.599609  15838.150391           0          0             0
2022-03-08 09:57:00+05:30  15838.150391  15838.250000  15830.150391  15830.750000           0          0             0
2022-03-08 09:58:01+05:30  15830.400391  15830.400391  15830.400391  15830.400391           0          0             0
```

if I will print df.tail(1), it will print

```
2022-03-08 09:58:01+05:30  15830.400391  15830.400391  15830.400391  15830.400391           0          0             0
```

But, I want to print the last row which has "00" seconds. For example, in this case, it should retrieve last row as "09:57:00" .
Output should be :

```
2022-03-08 09:57:00+05:30  15838.150391  15838.250000  15830.150391  15830.750000           0          0             0
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the index first

```
#df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

out = df[df.index.second==0].tail(1)
Out[644]: 
                                     Open          High  ...  Stock  Splits
2022-03-08 09:57:00+05:30  09:57:00+05:30  15838.150391  ...      0       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter datetime row with this.

```
df.Datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.Datetime)
df[df.Datetime.dt.second == 0].tail(1)
```